# Invalid frame `frame.index` on FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

While working on my project I came across a rather unique error

```
Warning: Failed frame type: Invalid frame `frame.index` of type `string` supplied to `VirtualizedList.getItemLayout`, expected `number`.
```

So with above warning it should be somewhere in **getItemLayout**, here is said code:

```
getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
    return {index, length: 45, offset: 45 * index}
}}
```

I fiddled around with the code a bit but was not able to figure out what is going wrong. Anyone came across this error by any change or has an idea of what could be causing this?

Full code:

```
const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onDatePressItem(item, index)}>
        {selectedDate === item ? (
        <View style={styles.selectedDateContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.selectedDateText}>{moment(item).format('D')}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.selectedDateText}>{moment(item).format('MMM')}</Text>
        </View>
        ) : (
        <View style={styles.unselectedDateContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.unselectedDateText}>{moment(item).format('D')}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.unselectedDateText}>{moment(item).format('MMM')}</Text>
        </View>
        )}
   </TouchableOpacity>
);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(date, index) => `${date + index}`}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListStyle}
            initialScrollIndex={closestIndex}
            getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
                return {index, length: 45, offset: 45 * index}
            }}
            ref={listRef}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        />
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Try to `console.log` `index` supplied to `getItemLayout` to see it's value

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli console.log of the index just returns the index as expected

Comment: `console.log(typeof(index))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i tried replicating your code, everything seems to be fine except for few lines

```
    const data = ['0', '1'];

    const App: () => Node = () => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <FlatList<string>
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(date, index) => `${date + index.toString()}`}
            initialScrollIndex={0}
            getItemLayout={(_, index) => {
              return {index, length: 45, offset: 45 * index};
            }}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
```

this line

```
keyExtractor={(date, index) => `${date + index.toString()}`}
```

typescript didn't like concatination date + index.

also i could not replicate this line

`initialScrollIndex={closestIndex}`

since you have not provided the closestIndex variable, so my best bet is that the bug is in this variable maybe.

Comment: Wow, I tried so hard for a few hours that I actually went to work on another part. Thanks, it was indeed the closestIndex which was a string, when I returned it as Integer it worked like a charm!

Comment: this is why i use typescript :D anyway glad i could help